# How big is the human Population in the future of the Terminator series?

Tags: the-terminator-series

I only saw the first 4 movies and some episodes of the TV-Series, so mabye this is mentioned in Genesys or some of the TV-Episodes or in a book.

When we see some scenes from the future, it is always about the resistance group of John Connor. 
There are several statemens that the human population is near extinction, I guess a big part died already because of the nuclear explosions seen in T3, but i can not remember an exact statement how many humans are still alive. Are there other resistance groups or not machine controlled areas on earth except John Connors Group in north america (Asia, Europe, etc...)? Is it ever mentioned or estimated how many humans are still alive on earth?

In Terminator 4 we see a little overview and can estimate the humans alive in Connors area, but I guess they are not more than some thousands, is this all that is left of human population in the future?

Comment: For some reason I remember 2 billion people as a number they say was left alive after the bombs fell. Cant support my claim so not making this the answer. The 2 billion quickly became less as there are many "work camps" where captured humans are "disposed off". There is the global resistance and those loyal to Skynet so deff more that a few thousand.

Comment: @Praxis: Hm, ok, i was hoping for a more detailed answer then "well below 2 billion", but i guess there is none. in consideration that the human population reached 1 billion people about 1800, your speculation still sounds like a lot of people to me. So the population is somewhere between thousands and 2 billion.

Comment: @kl78 : If I had to guess, I'd say it was probably only tens of thousands at most by 2029, but I didn't want to give a figure for which there is no evidence.  Unfortunately, Terminator series writers have always been very vague about humanity after Judgement Day.  (Thanks for accepting, btw!)

Comment: I estimate the surviving humans to number exactly 14.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the beginning of *Terminator: Genisys*, Kyle Reese is narrating, and says that on August 29, 1997,

> ***three billion people died in the nuclear fire.***

On June 30, 1997, the population of Earth is estimated to be 5,898,688,337, according to [GeoHive](http://www.geohive.com/earth/his_history3.aspx).

This means that **approximately 2.9 billion people survived Judgement Day**.

Given the conditions, many of those survivors would have died from malnutrition and radiation-induced illnesses in the ensuing years — not to mention being systematically eliminated by Skynet's Terminator program, which would have been in full force by the 2020s.

Lack of medical resources and food would also mean a lower birth rate and higher rates of infant mortality.

While this is speculation on my part, the surviving population could easily have dwindled to **well below 2 billion by 2029** — the infamous year when Skynet completed its time displacement device.

(Given the harsh conditions and systematic elimination of human survivors, there could be as few as *tens of thousands* of remaining humans by 2029 — but there is no canon statement to back that up.)